# Implementing lambda architecture using Hadoop, Apache Spark, HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, lambda-architecture

I want to implement lambda architecture with a simple example. I am not able to fit my technology stack into each layer of lambda architecture.

I want to find out top 10 popular hashtags in twitter tweets in real time. I am listing the purpose of each layer hare from http://lambda-architecture.net/.

- All **data** entering the system is dispatched to both the batch layer
  and the speed layer for processing.
- The **batch layer** has two functions: (i) managing the master dataset
  (an immutable, append-only set of raw data), and (ii) to pre-compute
  the batch views.
- The **serving layer** indexes the batch views so that they can be queried
  in low-latency, ad-hoc way.
- The **speed layer** compensates for the high latency of updates to the
  serving layer and deals with recent data only.
- Any incoming **query** can be answered by merging results from batch
  views and real-time views.

What part of my problem I can solve with each layer. I am working with Apache Spark & Hadoop HDFS technology stack.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this link can be helpful to you.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/09/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop/

Only you should consider Spark Core instead of using Hive after reading twitter data and moving it to the HDFS by using Flume.